# transforming 0 to 1 coordinates to other measurement

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-statistics

I am not experienced with ArcGIS and trying to perform some analysis on using the Statistics toolbox.

The dataset I'm using is the redwood dataset used by Diggle 1983. An example can be found [here](http://www.public.iastate.edu/~pcaragea/S40608/Notes/PointPatterns/PP_intro.pdf#page=3). The data I received is in coordinates from 0 to 1 but the area is actually 23 sqm.

I know how to display XY event in ArcMap for the 0...1 coordinates, but want all the calculations to be in meters and relevant to the scale.

Do I just multiply it in 23?